# dwarfdump - Debug Build Has No Symbols?

Tags: xcode, dwarf

I have built my project for iphoneos and iphonesimulator, both debug and release. When I run dwarfdump on the debug builds is reports empty. When I run it on the release build DSYMs it report all of the symbols.

See the output below (I only grabbed the first part of the DSYM output).

Why are the debug build empty?

---

### File: Debug-iphoneos/VerticonsToolbox.framework/VerticonsToolbox (arm64)

.debug_info contents:
< EMPTY >

---

### File: Debug-iphonesimulator/VerticonsToolbox.framework/VerticonsToolbox (x86_64)

.debug_info contents:
< EMPTY >

---

### File: Release-iphoneos/VerticonsToolbox.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/VerticonsToolbox (armv7)

.debug_info contents:

0x00000000: Compile Unit: length = 0x000013ad  version = 0x0003  abbr_offset = 0x00000000  addr_size = 0x04  (next CU at 0x000013b1)

0x0000000b: TAG_compile_unit [1] *
             AT_producer( "Apple Swift version 3.0.2 (swiftlang-800.0.63 clang-800.0.42.1)" )
             AT_language( DW_LANG_Swift )
             AT_name( "/Users/Robert/Development/iOS/VerticonsToolbox/VerticonsToolbox/UI/Application.swift" )
             AT_stmt_list( 0x00000000 )
             AT_comp_dir( "/Users/Robert/Development/iOS/VerticonsToolbox" )

---

### File: Release-iphonesimulator/VerticonsToolbox.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/VerticonsToolbox (i386)

.debug_info contents:

0x00000000: Compile Unit: length = 0x00001370  version = 0x0003  abbr_offset = 0x00000000  addr_size = 0x04  (next CU at 0x00001374)

0x0000000b: TAG_compile_unit [1] *
             AT_producer( "Apple Swift version 3.0.2 (swiftlang-800.0.63 clang-800.0.42.1)" )
             AT_language( DW_LANG_Swift )
             AT_name( "/Users/Robert/Development/iOS/VerticonsToolbox/VerticonsToolbox/UI/Application.swift" )
             AT_stmt_list( 0x00000000 )
             AT_comp_dir( "/Users/Robert/Development/iOS/VerticonsToolbox" )
             AT_APPLE_optimized( 0x01 )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On macOS, iOS, tvOS, watchOS, when you do a "dwarf" style build (see your Xcode project's build settings), the debug information is in the `.o` files, not the linked executable.  When you run `dsymutil` or you select a "dwarf + dSYM" style build setting, a `.dSYM` bundle is created with all of the debug information in the `.o` files collected into a single bundle / binary.

Comment: Shouldn't the linked executable still have debug information for the code in the executable target? Is there any way to dig into that debug info?